mail got uninstalled during upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04.5 to 24.04.1
mail is part of mailutils and was installed in Ubuntu 22.04.
From the session logs I understand mailutils was first upgraded from 1:3.14-1 to 1:3.17-1, but a bit later in the upgrade regarded as obsolete.
Is there a good reason mailutils got removed?
sudo do-release-upgrade

Line 1406: 20:02:04    Get:1062 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 mailutils-common all 1:3.17-1.1build3 [389 kB]   
Line 2411: 20:04:48    Removing mailutils (1:3.14-1) ...
Line 2579: 20:05:13     libmailutils8:amd64 depends on libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.2).
Line 2939: 20:06:19    Removing libmailutils8:amd64 (1:3.14-1) ...
Line 4830: 20:10:15    Preparing to unpack .../283-mailutils-common_1%3a3.17-1.1build3_all.deb ...
Line 4831: 20:10:15    Unpacking mailutils-common (1:3.17-1.1build3) over (1:3.14-1) ...
Line 5355: 20:10:54    Setting up mailutils-common (1:3.17-1.1build3) ...
           20:19:09    Searching for obsolete software
           20:19:13    Reading state information... Done
           20:19:13    Remove obsolete packages? 
           20:19:13    95 packages are going to be removed. 
Line 7678: 20:19:30    Removing mailutils-common (1:3.17-1.1build3) ...


Changing default python version in ubuntu is a certified way of destroying your installation. Please don't do that. Use virtual environment/Anaconda instead

Didn't find any reason not to just install 'mailutils-common' again.
But trying so it looks to reveal a possible reason for it to become removed.
In Ubuntu 22.04 I had to get Python3.12 which I got following https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/05/install-python-3-12-ubuntu/:
(and for Python3.11 https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/10/python-3-11-released-how-install-ubuntu/)
# sudo apt-get install mailutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.12t64 : Depends: libpython3.12-stdlib (= 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) but 3.12.6-1+jammy1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Google pointed to a similar case:
https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg6097257.html
and looking at my installation:
# apt list --installed | grep jammy
libpython3.11-minimal/now 3.11.10-1+jammy1 amd64 [installed,local]
libpython3.11-stdlib/now 3.11.10-1+jammy1 amd64 [installed,local]
libpython3.12-minimal/now 3.12.6-1+jammy1 amd64 [installed,local]
libpython3.12-stdlib/now 3.12.6-1+jammy1 amd64 [installed,local]
python3.11-minimal/now 3.11.10-1+jammy1 amd64 [installed,local]
python3.11/now 3.11.10-1+jammy1 amd64 [installed,local]
python3.12-minimal/now 3.12.6-1+jammy1 amd64 [installed,local]
python3.12/now 3.12.6-1+jammy1 amd64 [installed,local]

So I need to downgrade these packages to the once used by Ubuntu 24.04.1...
Python3.11 removal (don't use it, so should be fine to just remove it):
sudo apt remove --autoremove python3.11
Downgrade with:
sudo apt install '?installed?source-package(^python3.12$)/noble-updates'
After this I could install mail again with:
sudo apt-get install mailutils
